# Set maximum order quantity for Featured and Sale items

Tags: woocommerce, max

I'm using woocommerce & need to set the *maximum* quantity that can be ordered e.g. for promotional items (Featured and Sale items only). Fixed Qty.

Looked at Advanced Quantity & Various Min / Max quantity, but neither suited me
as it needs to be simple & quick to setup.

I found this code but it works Globally - I want to only apply to Featured and Sale items:

```php
/* Limit Quantity */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 ); 

function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
  //$args['input_value']    = 1;    // Starting value
  $args['max_value']        = 10;   // Maximum value
  $args['min_value']        = 1;    // Minimum value
  //$args['step']       = 1;    // Quantity steps
  return $args;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that those plugins aren't easy to set up?

Comment: I had a go ! - several dozens of products Featured + Sale.

Comment: I found this simple code to limit MAX Qty globally. If I could only limit it to Featured & Sale item - perhaps some IF statement but then my knowdge is limited /* Limit Quantity */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    //$args['input_value']  = 1; // Starting value
    $args['max_value']   = 10;  // Maximum value
    $args['min_value']   = 1;    // Minimum value
    //$args['step']   = 1;    // Quantity steps
    return $args;
}

Comment: Can you edit your question to add that code? No one can read it in the comments.